# Crystal Report exceed Processing Jobs Limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (dllselection.SelectedValue == "3")
            {
                ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                myDataReport.Load(Server.MapPath("OJT.rpt"));
                myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("intranet", "cpgintranet@2016", "192.168.2.5", "INTRANET");
                myDataReport.SetParameterValue("T-ID", TextBox1.Text);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

            }
            else if (dllselection.SelectedValue == "4")
            {
                ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                myDataReport.Load(Server.MapPath("TEFF.rpt"));
                myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("intranet", "cpgintranet@2016", "192.168.2.5", "INTRANET");
                myDataReport.SetParameterValue("T-ID", TextBox1.Text);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
if (dllselection.SelectedValue == "3")
            {
                ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                myDataReport.Load(Server.MapPath("OJT.rpt"));
                myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("intranet", "abc@2016", "192.168.2.88", "INTRANET");
                myDataReport.SetParameterValue("T-ID", TextBox1.Text);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

            }
            else if (dllselection.SelectedValue == "4")
            {
                ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                myDataReport.Load(Server.MapPath("TEFF.rpt"));
                myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("intranet", "abc@2016", "192.168.2.88", "INTRANET");
                myDataReport.SetParameterValue("T-ID", TextBox1.Text);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();


            }
}
```

i am getting error :

> The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system
>   administrator has been reached."

Having researched the topic online I found some solution,set registry value, specifically `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer\PrintJobLimit` to "-1" ,but this solution is not working,if I adding crystal report dispose and close function in my code,the crystal report I generated will be empty.
Below are my aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dllselection"  onchange="javascript:return dropdown(this);" runat="server" Style="border: groove" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="On Job Training" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Training Effectiveness Form" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <div id="dvReport">
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" PrintMode="Pdf" />
        </div>
```

Comment: You should try moving the setting of the report source to the page_init event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. There is a [maximum number of prints](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2014/04/25/what-exactly-is-maximum-report-processing-job-limit-for-crystal-reports) allowed by the crystal runtime provided for the .net framework. The way to ensure it doesn't happen is to clean up thoroughly in your page unload event.

First, promote your ReportDocument (myDataReport) to a private field in the page behind. Then you'll be able to dispose of the report and then set it to null:

```
protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
    CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
    myDataReport.Close(); // I can't remember if this is part of the reportDucment class
    myDataReport.Dispose();
    myDataReport = null;
    GC.Collect(); // I forgot this line
}
```

**Edit** added GC.Collect

You can tell you have this problem if you go to %temp% (it could vary in your case) there would be multiple copies of your report with a GUID appended to the file name cached, delete them all before you start. When you run the above cleanup every time, these files don't accumulate.